# Using Filter Function and Dynamically Changing Column Based on Value in Another Field

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel table called "Participants". I want to filter out the delegation name (in this formula `Participant[Delegation]` and the name of an event. There a series of different events indicated by different columns in the data. So, I want to dynamically change a field value and have that field value change the data column being filters. As I understand, I should use the INDIRECT function to turn the dynamic field into text that be used by the FILTER formula.

I have been playing with an INDIRECT function nested within a FILTER function to dynamically set the column that is returned. My formula below doesn't seem to work. Can someone show me where I went wrong?

`=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Participants, (Participants[Delegation]=C2)*(INDIRECT(TEXT(Participants,"[") & C3 & "]")=C3), "No Records Found"), 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data looks like this :

[image]

You could try using HSTACK function instead of CHOOSECOLS:

```
=FILTER(HSTACK(Participants[Participant], Participants[Delegation], INDIRECT("Participants["&C3&"]")), Participants[Delegation]=C2)
```

The first argument of the FILTER function would be the HSTACK function. In the HSTACK, you simply select the columns that you want to return. Adding one with INDIRECT makes it dynamic.

Of course, wrapping this in an IFERROR would handle the potential errors. You could also limit the values entered in C3 with data validation, to make sure the column exists.